# I know WMS, WMTS, and WFS, but what is an OWS?

Tags: gis

Sorry to ask that beginner question.

I know `WMS`, `WFS` and `WPS`, but I fall upon the `OWS` kind of protocol. I can't figure what is under it.

What is its purpose ? Is it a kind of `WMS` ou `WFS` ? Does it has advantages over others ones ?

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OWS` is not a protocol. It's a stand-in term for (I believe) `OGC Web Service` - basically it means its an endpoint that could be hosting any of the OGC services. It's commonly seen on GeoServer endpoints.

So for example:

http://www.example.com/geoserver/wms - would in theory be an endpoint for just WMS.

Whereas

http://www.example.com/geoserver/ows - would be an endpoint that could serve any of WMS, WFS, WCS, WMTS.

Comment: And let's not forget TinyOWS, a WFS-T implementation!